# What's the difference between Kapt and Implementation in Gradle when declaring dependecies using them?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

What is the difference between `kapt` and `implementation` in Gradle when declaring dependencies and when should one be used over another?

Example:

```
//Room Components
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$rootProject.roomVersion"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$rootProject.roomVersion"

// dagger
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$rootProject.ext.daggerVersion"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android processor:$rootProject.ext.daggerVersion"
```

Comment: `kapt` and `implementation` are not analogous. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47224294/can-i-use-compileonly-as-a-replacement-for-annotationprocessor-in-gradle) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44493378/whats-the-difference-between-implementation-and-compile-in-gradle) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44413952/gradle-implementation-vs-api-configuration) [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50027741/android-project-with-java-and-kotlin-files-kapt-or-annotationprocessor)

Answer (score 1):

In short: implementation and kapt are not related directly

When it comes to kotlin, you use kapt where Java uses annotationProcessor.

Which one to use?
Depends on how the lib works

Check it out

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies?hl=pt-br

Answer (score 0):

1. You need kotlin-kapt to enable the
   annotation processor.
2. you can use kapt to enable the Dagger annotation processing in the app module